# ExecutionHook with parallel runner

Tags: karate

I am using the parallel runner to run one of m feature files. It has 8 scenarios as of now. I wanted to integrate a third party reporting plugin (Extent report) to build out the reports. I planned to use the ExecutionHook interface to try and achieve this. Below are the issues i faced and havent found a even after looking at the documentation.

**My issues**

1. I am creating a new test on the **afterFeature** method. This gives me 2 handles, Feature and ExecutionContext. However since the tests are running in parallel, the reporting steps are getting mixed on each other? How do i handle this? Any out of the box method i can use?
2. To counter the above, i decided to build the whole report towards the end on the **afterAll** overridden method but here i am missing the execution context data so i cant use the context.getRequestBuilder() to get the urls and paths.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please focus on the 1.0 release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Reasons:

- it gives you a way to build the whole report at the end, and the `Results` object can iterate over all `ScenarioResult` instances
- `ExecutionHook` has been changed to `RuntimeHook`, see [example](https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle/blob/karate-1-0/src/test/java/KarateHook.java)
- yes, since tests can run in parallel, it is up to you to synchronize as the framework has to be high performance, but building reports at the end using the `Results` object is recommended instead of using the `RuntimeHook`

Comment: Thanks Peter. Excited to try out the 1.0. This framework has been a revelation for me.