# Karate - how to configure the afterScenario hook in a called feature?

Tags: karate

I have the following use case. The top level feature file (test1.feature) calls two other feature files (test2.feature, test3.feature) like so:

test1.feature:

```
Feature:

Background:
    * print 'this is a background 1'

Scenario: test1
    * print 'this is test1'
    * call read('test2.feature')
    * call read('test3.feature')
```

test2.feature:

```
Feature:

Background:
    * print 'this is a background 2'
    * def testId = 222
    * configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.write({ id: testId, errorMessage: karate.info.errorMessage }, 'test-id-' + testId + '.json'); }

Scenario: test2
    * print 'this is test2'
```

test3.feature:

```
Feature:

Background:
    * print 'this is a background 3'
    * def testId = 333
    * configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.write({ id: testId, errorMessage: karate.info.errorMessage }, 'test-id-' + testId + '.json'); }

Scenario: test3
    * print 'this is test3'
```

I realize that writing to a file is not recommended, but in this particular case, I need to capture the test result for post execution processing (long story!). I'm also aware that the `Background` gets loaded for every `Feature/Scenario`. So once the calling feature (test1.feature) calls the first called feature (test2.feature), its `Background` takes over. And this is where I'd like the `afterScenario` hook from the called feature to be invoked, but since the calling feature (test1.feature) has not finished, it then proceeds to call the last feature (test3.feature). Similarly the `Background` from the the last called feature (test3.feature) gets loaded and since the calling feature (test1.feature) is now done, it then invokes the `afterScenario` hook from the last called feature (test3.feature), and as a result **only** `test-id-333.json` file gets written to the `target` folder. Here's the print output:

```
23:53:49.613 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is a background 1
23:53:49.617 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is test1
23:53:49.631 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is a background 2
23:53:49.637 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is test2
23:53:49.652 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is a background 3
23:53:49.654 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] this is test3
```

I know that this is the expected behavior, but was wondering if there is a way to invoke the `afterScenario` hook in the called feature (test2.feature), even if the calling feature (test1.feature) has still work to do.
If I turn the test1.feature into a `Scenario Outline`, then both files `test-id-222.json` and `test-id-333.json` get written, since now they're each separate scenario, but unfortunately this option is not viable in this use case.

It'd be nice if there was a `afterThisScenario`, or a parameter to pass to a called feature i.e. `* call read('test2.feature') withAfterHook`, that would ensure the after hook gets invoked, even if the calling feature is still not finished.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

That's a little tricky to design for because you can even do this in the global `karate-config.js`:

```
karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){ karate.log('after scenario') });
```

And we also have a rule that `afterScenario` applies only to the "top level" feature and will do nothing in "called" features.

So I propose 2 options.

1. We have a concept of `RuntimeHook` (used to be called [`ExecutionHook`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65986327/143475)) but you need to write some Java code, and this is somewhat un-documented, intended for advanced users. But you
   have full control and can read runtime metadata such as the feature name, scenario name etc.
2. define a re-usable function that takes `test-id` as a parameter and manually call it at the end of each block of code. But I think I see your point, you probably want this to fire even if there was an error. You can submit a feature request for an `onError` hook which I have been considering.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, Peter! I've submitted a feature request for an `onError` hook here -> https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1465 In the meantime, I'll look into the `RuntimeHook`

Comment: @PeterThomas `karate.configure('afterFeature', function() { karate.log('after feature') });`  should it work in the same way?

Comment: @Egor as far as I know - yes

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue as follows:

test1.feature:

```
Feature:

Background:
    * print 'this is a background 1'
    * def testIds = [222, 333]
    * call read('../resources/write-test-results.js') testIds

Scenario: test1
    * print 'this is test1'
    * call read('test2.feature')
    * karate.write({ id: testId, errorMessage: null }, 'test-id-' + testId + '.json')

    * call read('test3.feature')
```

write-test-results.js (located in test/resources):

```
function fn(ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        karate.write({ id: ids[i], errorMessage: 'Skipped' }, 'test-id-' + ids[i] + '.json')
    }
}
```

*test2.feature* and *test3.feature* remain unchanged.

**Explanation:**

- The "top level" feature (*test1.feature*) will create two files in the `target` directory *test-id-222.json* and *test-id-333.json* with the following contents:

```
{"id":222,"errorMessage":"Skipped"}
{"id":333,"errorMessage":"Skipped"}
```

as a result of calling the *write-test-results.js* function in the `Background` section.

- Then the next "called" feature (*test2.feature*) will reload the `Background` and if it passes, the "top level" feature will overwrite the *test-id-222.json* file with this line:

```
* karate.write({ id: testId, errorMessage: null }, 'test-id-' + testId + '.json')
```

- Finally, it will call the last "called" feature (*test3.feature*) and since its `Background` will take over, the `afterScenario` hook will overwrite the *test-id-333.json* file with the actual test result.

So, if *test2.feature* fails, the *test-id-222.json* file will get overwritten with the actual error, and *test-id-333.json* will remain unchanged and reflect the result of *test3.feature*, namely `Skipped`.

```
{"id":333,"errorMessage":"Skipped"}
```